# Explanation of Matlab's bwlabel,regionprops & centroid functions

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, centroid

I have spent all day reading up on the above MATLAB functions. I can't seem to find any good explanations online, even on the MathWorks website!

I would be very grateful if anyone could explain `bwlabel`, `regionprops` and `centroid`.  How do they work if applied to a grayscale image?

Specifically, they are being used in this code below. How do the above functions apply to the code below?

```
fun=@minutie; L = nlfilter(K,[3 3],fun); 
%% Termination LTerm=(L==1); 
figure; imshow(LTerm) 
LTermLab=bwlabel(LTerm); 
propTerm=regionprops(LTermLab,'Centroid'); 
CentroidTerm=round(cat(1,LTerm(:).Centroid)); 
figure; imshow(~K) 
set(gcf,'position',[1 1 600 600]); hold on 
plot(CentroidTerm(:,1),CentroidTerm(:,2),'ro')
```

Comment: This requires access to "`minutie`".  I'm assuming you are looking at some fingerprint recognition or analysis code so this is probably trying to make the minutie points of your fingers more pronounced.  `nlfilter` stands for non-linear filter.  You are choosing a 3 x 3 pixel neighbourhood and analyzing these sized neighbourhoods, and applying that function to each neighbourhood in your image.  I wouldn't have used `bwlabel` as they're treating it as a binary image, but after you detect minutie points, you detect the centroids and display the point where the first centroid is in the image.

Comment: I also don't understand why you've asked this question when you've already asked for clarification of this code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982080/matlab-fingerprint-minutia-extraction - Jigg's explanation is fine.

Answer (score 22):

That's quite a mouthful to explain!... nevertheless, I'd love to explain it to you.  However, I'm a bit surprised that you couldn't understand the documentation from MathWorks.  It's actually quite good at explaining a lot (if not all...) of their functions.

<s>BTW, `bwlabel` and `regionprops` are **not defined** for grayscale images.  You can only apply these to **binary** images</s>.

**Update:** `bwlabel` still has the restriction of accepting a binary image but `regionprops` no longer has this restriction.  It can also take in a **label** matrix that is usually output from `bwlabel` as well as binary images.

Assuming binary images is what you want, my explanations for each function is as follows.

---

## `bwlabel`

[`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) takes in a binary image.  This binary image should contain a bunch of objects that are separated from each other.  Pixels that belong to an object are denoted with `1` / `true` while those pixels that are the background are `0` / `false`.  For example, suppose we have a binary image that looks like this:

```
0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

You can see in this image that there are **four** objects in this image.  The definition of an object are those pixels that are `1` that are connected in a chain by looking at local neighbourhoods.  We usually look at 8-pixel neighbourhoods where you look at the North, Northeast, East, Southeast, South, Southwest, West, Northwest directions.  Another way of saying this is that the objects are **8-connected**.  For simplicity, sometimes people look at 4-pixel neighbourhoods, where you just look at the North, East, South and West directions.  This woudl mean that the objects are **4-connected**.

The output of `bwlabel` will give you an integer map where each object is **assigned a unique ID**.  As such, the output of `bwlabel` would look something like this:

```
0  0  0  0  0  3  3  3  0  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  3  3  0  0
0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  4
0  0  2  2  2  2  0  0  4  4
```

Because MATLAB processes things in column major, that's why the labelling is how you see above.  As such, `bwlabel` gives you the **membership** of each pixel.  This tells you where each pixel belongs to if it falls on an object.  `0` in this map corresponds to the background.  To call `bwlabel`, you can do:

```
L = bwlabel(img);
```

`img` would be the binary image that you supply to the function and `L` is the integer map I just talked about.  Additionally, you can provide 2 outputs to `bwlabel`, and the second parameter tells you how many objects exist in the image.  As such:

```
[L, num] = bwlabel(img);
```

With our above example, `num` would be 4.  As another method of invocation, you can specify the connected pixel neighbourhoods you would examine, and so you can do this:

```
[L, num] = bwlabel(img, N);
```

`N` would be the pixel neighbourhood you want to examine (i.e. 4 or 8).

---

## `regionprops`

[`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) is a very useful function that I use daily.  `regionprops` measures a variety of image quantities and features in a black and white image.  Specifically, given a black and white image it automatically determines the properties of each contiguous white region that is 8-connected.  One of these particular properties is the **centroid**.  This is also the centre of mass.  You can think of this as the "middle" of the object.  This would be the `(x,y)` locations of where the middle of each object is located.  As such, the `Centroid` for `regionprops` works such that  for each object that is seen in your image, this would calculate the centre of mass for the object and the output of `regionprops` would return a structure where each element of this structure would tell you what the centroid is for each of the objects in your black and white image.  `Centroid` is just one of the properties.  There are other useful features as well, but I'm assuming you don't want to do this.  To call `regionprops`, you would do this:

```
s = regionprops(img, 'Centroid');
```

The above code will calculate the centroids of each of your objects in the image.  You can specify additional flags to `regionprops` to specify each feature that you want.  I do highly encourage that you take a look at all of the possible features that `regionprops` can calculate, as there are many that are useful in a variety of different applications and situations.

Also, by omitting any flags as input into the function, you would calculate **all** of the features in your image by default.  Therefore, if we were to declare the image that we have seen above in MATLAB, this is what would happen after I run `regionprops`.  After, let's calculate what the centroids are:

```
img = logical(...
   [0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0;
    0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0;
    0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0;
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1;
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1;
    0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1]);
s = regionprops(img, 'Centroid');
```

... and finally when we display the centroids:

```
>> disp(cat(1,s.Centroid))

3.0000    2.6000
4.5000    6.0000
7.2000    1.4000
9.6000    5.2000
```

As such, the first centroid is located at `(x,y) = (3, 2.6)`, the next centroid is located at `(x,y) = (4.5, 6)` and so on.  Take special note that the `x` co-ordinate is the **column** while the `y` co-ordinate is the **row**.

---

Hope this is clear!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. However, all of the above are used in the code I have included above. Can you explain to me what the code does?? I am very interested to find out. I have spent a long while trying to figure it out but having no luck :(

Comment: @rayryeng Do you know how `regionprops` behaves in Matlab 2016a? I am getting 0x1 struct now in Matlab 2016a, while I got totally different results in older Matlabs. I opened a new thread about the case here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35970657/54964