# Extract sub-matrices from binary matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Say binary matrix `m`:

```
      # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 # [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [3,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
 # [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
 # [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
 # [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [7,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
 # [8,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1
 # [9,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0

m <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 9L))
```

How we can extract those `1`-valued sub-matrices? e.g.

```
m[7:9,8:9]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    1
```

The point is that I want to extract them algorithmtically not indexing them explicitly like `m[7:9,8:9]`.

- The input is a binary matrix
- List of sub-matrices as output (so list of four matrices of dim `3*4`, `2*2`, `3*2` and `3*2`)
- Sub-matrices are `1`-valued rectangular
- The border of the sub-matrices are secured with zeros.

Comment: You seem to have found the answer yourself … What is your desired input and output like?

Comment: You want to find all sub-matrix which contain only 1?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Input a binary matrix, output a list of `1`-valued sub-matrices. I do not want to index them explicitly but rather extract them algorithmically.

Comment: So in other words for your example the output would be a list of four matrices?

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, four matrices of dim `3*4`, `2*2`, `3*2` and `3*2`

Comment: Are the submatrices guaranteed to be rectangular? Or would you have to account for something like `m2 <- m; m2[9,3] <- 1; m2`?

Comment: @nrussell yes, all are rectangular so no case like `m2`

Comment: But if all matrices are guaranteed to be reactangular, then `m[7:8, 2:3]` would not be recognized as `ncol(m[7:8, 2:3])  == nrow(m[7:8, 2:3])`, see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularMatrix.html

Comment: Actually, extending @nrussell's example, what is more ambiguous is what happens when `m2 = m; m2[2, 6] = m2[2, 7] = 1`. Which submatrix should be identified -- the tall one (2, 6) -- (5, 7), the wide one (3, 4) -- (5, 7), or both?

Comment: @tchakravarty the border of the sub-matrices are secured with zeros. So `m2` cannot be the case.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would say that the *internal* borders of the sub-matrices are secured by zeros. It isn't the case that these sub-matrices are completely surrounded by zeros.

Comment: A row-by-row approach could work. With each new row, some previous rectangles are permanently secured, some grow, some are eliminated (by violation of the secured-by-zeros condition) and some new ones spawn. By the time you process the final row -- you are done. Start by writing a function which does what you want in the 1-D case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd treat it as a spatial problem where you have a raster and want to detect regions of connected cells.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(m)

library(igraph)
rc <- clump(r)

plot(rc, col = rainbow(rc@data@max))
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
m1 <- as.matrix(rc)

lapply(seq_len(rc@data@max), function(x) {
  inds <- which(m1 == x, arr.ind = TRUE)
  nrow <- diff(range(inds[, "row"])) + 1
  ncol <- diff(range(inds[, "col"])) + 1
  matrix(1, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)
})
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    1    1
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#
#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    1
#
#[[4]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `focal` in the raster package with an appropriate weighting matrix `w`.  It.  convolves `w` with `m` giving a matrix the same dimensions as `m` with the value of  `big` at each upper left corner and other values elsewhere so comparing it to `big` gives a logical matrix which is TRUE at upper left corners of rectangles.   Using `which` we get `rc` which has one row per rectange and two columns representing the i and j coordinates of the upper left of that rectangle. The `Map` call iterates over the upper left coordinates invoking `genmap` on each.  `genmap` uses `rle` (as defined in the `rl` function)  to find the length of the run of ones in each coordinate direction and returns a matrix of ones having those dimensions.

```
library(raster)

big <- 100
r <- raster(m)
w <- matrix(0, 3, 3); w[1:2, 1:2] <- 1; w[2, 2] <- big
rc <- which(as.matrix(focal(r, w, pad = TRUE, padValue = 0)) == big, arr = TRUE)

rl <- function(x) rle(x)$lengths[1]
genmat <- function(i, j) matrix(1, rl(m[i:nrow(m), j]), rl(m[i, j:ncol(m)]))
Map(genmat, rc[, 1], rc[, 2])
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
```

**Updates** Simplified code.

Answer (score 3):

A rather long-winded answer, but you can do this via image labeling as I did in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959470/r-count-objects-in-a-picture/38962379#38962379). This will extend nicely to non-rectangular blobs of 1's.

```
find.contiguous <- function(img, x, bg) {
  ## we need to deal with a single (row,col) matrix index
  ## versus a collection of them in a two column matrix separately.
  if (length(x) > 2) {
    lbl <- img[x][1]
    img[x] <- bg
    xc <- x[,1]
    yc <- x[,2]
  } else {
    lbl <- img[x[1],x[2]]
    img[x[1],x[2]] <- bg
    xc <- x[1]
    yc <- x[2]
  }    
  ## find all neighbors of x
  xmin <- ifelse((xc-1) < 1, 1, (xc-1))
  xmax <- ifelse((xc+1) > nrow(img), nrow(img), (xc+1))
  ymin <- ifelse((yc-1) < 1, 1, (yc-1))
  ymax <- ifelse((yc+1) > ncol(img), ncol(img), (yc+1))
  ## find all neighbors of x
  x <- rbind(cbind(xmin, ymin),
             cbind(xc  , ymin),
             cbind(xmax, ymin),
             cbind(xmin, yc),
             cbind(xmax, yc),
             cbind(xmin, ymax),
             cbind(xc  , ymax),
             cbind(xmax, ymax))
  ## that have the same label as the original x
  x <- x[img[x] == lbl,]
  ## if there is none, we stop and return the updated image
  if (length(x)==0) return(img);
  ## otherwise, we call this function recursively
  find.contiguous(img,x,bg)
}
```

`find.contiguous` is a recursive function in which for each call it receives:

1. A working copy of the image `img`.
2. A collection of pixel (matrix) indices `x` (row,col) that belong to an object in the image `img`.
3. The background value `bg`

`find.contiguous` then proceeds to:

1. Set all pixels at `x` in `img` to the `bg` color. This marks that we have visited the pixels.
2. Find all neighboring pixels of `x` that have the same label (value) as that in `x`. This grows the region of the same object. Note that since `x` is not necessarily a single pixel, `x` grows *geometrically* so that, in fact, this function is no slouch.
3. If there are no more neighbors belonging to the same object, we return the updated image; otherwise, we make the recursive call.

Starting from a single pixel that correspond to an object, a call to `find.contiguous` will grow the region to include all the object's pixels and return an updated image where the object is replaced by the background. This process can then be repeated in a loop until there are no more objects in the image, hence the ability to extract all sub-matrices of 1's.

With your data:

```
m <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 9L))
## make a copy to img which will be converted to all-zeros in the process 
## as matrices of 1's are extracted by the process
img <- m
## get all pixel coordinates that are objects
x <- which(img==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
## loop until there are no more pixels that are objects
##the output is in the list out
count <- 0
out <- list()
while (length(x) > 0) {
  ## choose a single (e.g., first) pixel location. This belongs to the current
  ## object that we will grow and remove from the image using find.contiguous
  if (length(x) > 2) {
    x1 <- x[1,]
  }
  ## make the call to remove the object from img
  img <- find.contiguous(img, x1, 0)
  ## find the remaining pixel locations belonging to objects
  xnew <- which(img==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
  count <- count + 1
  ## extract the indices for the 1's found by diffing new with x 
  out.ind <- x[!(x[,1] %in% xnew[,1] & x[,2] %in% xnew[,2]),]
  ## set it as a matrix in the output
  out[[count]] <- matrix(m[out.ind],nrow=length(unique(out.ind[,1])),ncol=length(unique(out.ind[,2])))
  x <- xnew
}
```

Your output is the list `out`:

```
print(out)
##[[1]]
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    1    1
##[2,]    1    1
##
##[[2]]
##     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
##[1,]    1    1    1    1
##[2,]    1    1    1    1
##[3,]    1    1    1    1
##
##[[3]]
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    1    1
##[2,]    1    1
##[3,]    1    1
##
##[[4]]
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    1    1
##[2,]    1    1
##[3,]    1    1
```

Note that you can just as easily output the locations of the extracted 1's from `out.ind`: