# Cluster groups of 1s in a binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binary

I'm looking to create clusters around all `1`s and `0`s. Similar to Mindsweeper, I want to basically "draw a circle" around all `1`s, and create a border where `0`s exist.

I have tried using `hclust()` and creating a distance matrix, but the actual table I am working with is very large, and I have run into problems with run time.

```
test_matrix  <- matrix(c( 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,     
                          1,1,1,0,0,1,0,
                          0,1,0,0,0,1,0,
                          0,0,0,1,1,1,0,
                          0,0,0,1,1,1,1),nrow=5)
```

Result looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
```

My rules are as follows: If any `1` is connected to any `1` via UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, DIAGONAL(any direction), continue growing the "cluster". Based on these rules (8 points of connection for every point), I can spot four unique clusters with isolated `1`s.

How would you code to find these groups?

Comment: Please clarify your desired result. I.e. what is the link between "Result looks like this" and 'test_matrix'? Anyway, according to the description in your _final_ section, it sounds like you are looking for `library(raster)`; `clump(raster(m))`. If so, related: [Extract sub-matrices from binary matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263212/extract-sub-matrices-from-binary-matrix-in-r)

Comment: Could indicate whether below answer did solve your problem?

Comment: Could reply to comment asking for clarification and providing a potential solution?

Answer (score 12):

I think clustering is the right approach here, but you choose a poor ( computationally expensive) method for the task. I would go for DBSCAN like this:

```
library(dbscan)

## slightly altered test matrix to include a "cluster" with a single 1
test_matrix  <- matrix(c( 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,     
                          1,1,1,0,0,1,0,
                          0,1,0,0,0,1,0,
                          0,0,0,1,1,1,0,
                          1,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                          nrow=5, byrow = TRUE)

## find rows and columns of 1s
ones_pos <- which(test_matrix > 0,arr.ind=TRUE)


## perform DBSCAN clustering
## setting eps = sqrt(2) + .1 corresponds to your neighbourhood definition
## setting minPts = 2 will mark clusters of one point as noise
clust <- dbscan(ones_pos, eps = sqrt(2), minPts = 2)

## find the indices of noise elements
singular_ones <- ones_pos[clust$cluster == 0, ]

singular_ones
#> row col 
#>  5   1
```

To find all clusters (including those that just consist of one 1) just set `minPts` to 1. In this case there can be no noise. The cluster membership is stored in `clust$cluster`.

I am quite certain this approach will also be quite fast with large matrices.

Comment: Made an edit removing the usage of `dplyr` which is way unnecessary in this case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks! Does this work if I want to look for all clusters, some with just one point? Others with many? All in the same test?

Comment: This finds all clusters. Each cluster with more than `minPts` 1s gets assigned a number >=1. All other 1s get assigned 0 in `clust$cluster`