# How to find centroid of an object in divided image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, centroid

I have a binary image and divided this image into multiple blocks. e.g. a (60x60) image divided into 4 blocks

`(30x30) (30x30)
 (30x30) (30x30)`

Now I want to calculate the centroid of each block, I look up for a formula to do that and ended up with

[image: Centroid Formula]

How can I do that using matlab, and what is the difference between this method and `regionprops(...,'Centroid')`

**Update 1:**
This is what I've written so far...

```
m = 2;
n = 2;
im = imread('C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Samples\0_1.bmp');
flippedIm = 1-im;
boundary = regionprops(flippedIm, 'BoundingBox');
boundedIm = vertcat(boundary(1).BoundingBox);
xmin = boundedIm(1);
ymin = boundedIm(2);
width = boundedIm(3);
height = boundedIm(4);
croppedIm = imcrop(flippedIm,[xmin ymin width height]);

%USE X TO TEST
x = reshape(1:9,3,3)';
x = myPadding(x,m,n);

%a contains cells (blocks)
a = mySplit(x,m,n);

measurements = regionprops(x,'Centroid');
display(measurements(1));
```

And the result of that code is ...

```
measurements = 

9x1 struct array with fields:

Centroid
```

Comment: The centroid calculated by `regionprops` should be identical to the one calculated by your formula. Are you getting different results? Why is it significant that your image is divided into 4 blocks? Unless there is something missing from your question, if you can find the centroid of one image you can find the centroids of 4 images.

Comment: And what have you done?

Comment: @smttsp I have added what I did so far

Comment: @beaker `regionprops` gives me a 9x1 struct array as I mentioned above, shouldn't centroid be  (x,y) coordinates? why it give me 9x1 values? Sorry but can you explain to me where is my wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: @rayryeng I still don't get it, you mean that one image can have more than one centroid?

Comment: @HossamHoussien You are using `regionprops` on non-binary image that has values from 1 to 9 in a 3 x 3 grid.  The effect of this is that it treats each pixel as a separate object - That's why you have 9 centroids and thus have a 9 element structure array.  If you examined each centroid of the structure array, you will see that it's exactly equal to the locations of each element in the 3 x 3 grid.  Simply put, you are not using the function properly with the given input.

Comment: BTW, I think you may have meant to use `a` in your `regionprops` call instead of `x`, but `x` is still a non-binary matrix.  You need to either convert to binary, or ensure that the input is really what you want.

Comment: @rayryeng I understand now, also your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984775/6365031) helped a lot. Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @HossamHoussien Ah :) I wrote that answer a long time ago.  It is my pleasure.